# Why did Gordon make Evey the same breakfast and also saying bonjour to her?

Tags: plot-explanation, v-for-vendetta

In the movie *V for Vendetta* when Evey flees to Gordon, he makes her the same breakfast that V had made for her just the day before and he also said bonjour when he saw her.

Was that really a coincidence or did it actually mean anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it is cleared up quickly within the same scene that Gordon is not V 'diguised within a well fed exterior', the scene appears to be the first overt reference to the fact that 'V' both represents and could be any member of the oppressed society shown in the film.

As well as showing that Gordon shares many of the same traits as V (the cooking, the language, the mini - 'Shadow Gallery' of subversive and /or censored art), the scenes that he shares with Evey appear to be the beginning of her upward trajectory, one that ultimately leads to her assisting V with his final act and, through the closing shots of the film, her recognition that while V was a specific individual to her, his actions and the the very concept of his existence are universal to the downtrodden denizens of the Norsefire regime.

TL;DR

It's a coincidence with meaning.